# Should app to send daily digest be a part of website solution?

Tags: django, software-design, cron-task

I am developing a website using Django framework. I have built a solution "blogsite". I am sending daily mails as digest to subscribers. I have a python app which is being scheduled using cron-tab.
Should this app be made part of my website solution for completeness or should be treated as separate project?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you a) build your daily mail digest functions in a new app within the same project; and then b) create a [custom django-admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) that aggregates and sends your digest. That way, whenever you run a set command (for example, `python manage.py send_digests`), your digests will be sent.

Then, you can schedule a regular job with your hosting provider to run `python manage.py send_digests` daily. For example, if you're on Heroku, you can use [Heroku Scheduler](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

There can not be a ultimate answer on this but you have to decide yourself.

pro seperation (status quo):

- [Seperation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)
- Never change a running system

pro integration to django:

- [Dry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), If you have a database that is maintained by django - you could get the E-Mail adresses and User-Names from there

I do not claim that this list contains all aspects. You might come up with own thoughts. As soon one side becomes significantly larger you should change.